# How to upload folder of files to solr

Tags: solr

All:

I wonder what is a best way to upload a folder of pdf files into solr for indexing?

Right now, what I am doing is generate a files list, and for each file I initiate a request to solr for indexing, but it seems waste a lot of overload, so I wondering if I can use one request to upload all those files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about the performance, your best bet is to run Apache Tika on your client side and just send the final extracted content document to Solr. That's the most efficient way and then you could batch multiple extractions together.

Solr extract code just runs Tika under the covers.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have not touch anypart about Tika, but anyway, suppose after I have the extract done by Tika, what is the best way to upload those extracted document?

Comment: Use something like SolrJ to talk to Solr from a Java client.

Comment: Thanks for help. Another question I got is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806002/how-to-upload-pdf-and-update-field-within-one-request-in-solr

Comment: Could you help me with this first. Cos right now I do use SolrJ to upload pdf files but I can not update field at the same time.