# How to upload pdf and update field within one request in solr

Tags: solr, solrj

All:

I am new to solr and solrj. What I want to do right now is uploading pdf file to solr and set customized field such as last_modified field at same time.

But I keep encounter the error such as " multiple values encountered for non multiValued field last_modified", I use solrj to upload pdf and set the last_modified field like

```
ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
up.setParam("literal.last_modified", "2011-05-19T09:00:00Z");
```

I guess the error is due to when solr extract the pdf, it uses some meta data as last_modified field value as well so that my custmized last_modified value leads to a multivalue error, but I wonder **how to replace the meta data with my custmized data**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*/update/extract* is defined in *solrconfig.xml* for your core. You can see the configuration there and modify it to match it to your particular scenario. The [Reference Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika) lists the options.

In your particular scenario, something look strange. The parameter that seems to be relevant is **literalsOverride** but it is true by default. Perhaps, you are setting it to *false* somewhere.

You can also try explicitly map Tika's last update field to some different name.

I would enable catch-all (dynamicField *) as **store=true** and see what is being captured. Then you can play with the parameters until you are happy. You don't have to restart Solr, just reload the core from the Admin UI.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to find this literalsOverride in both schema.xml and solrconfig.xml, but there is none. Could you tell me where it is? In my schema.xml, the field last_modified is like:  <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/> and the update/extract handler is like: <lst name="defaults"><str name="lowernames">true</str><str name="uprefix">ignored_</str><str name="captureAttr">true</str><str name="fmap.a">links</str><str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str></lst>

Comment: Try setting it explicitly and see if it makes a difference. Maybe the default changed between versions of Solr.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to add it explicitly in solrconfig.xml like this:   <requestHandler name="/update/extract" startup="lazy" class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
      <str name="literalsOverride">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
But it does not work, what else do you think I should config?

Comment: Try my other suggestion (about dynamicField) and see what you get. If you are still stuck, you may want to ask this on the Solr Users mailing list, where more people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue, where I need to fetch one dynamic field value and do some operation then update it. I use below code to achieve this.
First check for that field is it exist or not. Try using below code may be it will help you.

```
    Map<String, String> partialUpdate = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if(alreadyPresent)
        {
            partialUpdate.put("set", value);
        }else
        {
            partialUpdate.put("add", value); 
        }

        doc.addField("projectId", projectId); // unique id for solrdoc 
        doc.addField(keys[0], partialUpdate); 

        docs.add(doc);
        solrServer.add(docs);
        solrServer.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try this code with solrJ. But one thing before that is:  My different situation is I am sure all  pdf files I uploaded is new( the id is never used before, so there is no need to check alreadyPresent, and by the way: how to check if a field already exist?), I just want to update certain field which is taken by solr pdf index processor( the processor may automatically generate a last_modified single value field) with the "uploading request", rather than submit another request to update them manually. Could you tell me how to specify that in upload URL string?